# Looking for ways to deduce selector classifications

Tags: smalltalk

I'm working on an a `SelectorClassifierAssistant` object that suggests possible classifications for a method.

So far I've implemented the following strategies:

1. local classifications of same selector (i.e., in the same hierarchy up and down)
2. other classifications of the same selector in other classes (sorted by frequency)
3. accessor detection (is the method a setter or a getter? `ifTrue: [^#accessing]`)
4. known selector prefixes (#is..., #print..., #as..., etc.)

and, if all of the above fail (i.e., suggestions is empty):

5. categories of other messages sent in the method (only the ones understood in the method's class and superclasses)

Are there other known heuristics I could use?

---EDIT---

6. selectors only sent from the same class -> #private (@Carlos E. Ferro)
7. known selectors (#= #hash, etc. -> #comparing and so on)
8. empty categories (if a category is empty chances are that the user just added it for classifying the next selector.)

Comment: Where can we find your `SelectorClassifierAssistant`?

Comment: That's a very interesting question. Your list seems pretty good. Keep us posted on your findings. I am not so much interested in automatic classification, but I would love to read a style guide. I am also interested in the usage of gerunds as protocol names.

Comment: @MartinW the usage of gerunds comes from how you read the protocol: *Methods for accessing*, etc., as profusely illustrated in the Blue Book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your last option, instead of looking at categories of messages sent in the method to classify, it would be better to look for categories of the senders of this message.

This is a heuristic that I often use.

The reason I found is that methods called from this one most likely are general services, but senders of this one consider it as a service and define an ¨area of interest¨ where this message is used.

---- EDIT ----

Another related heuristic, very simple is this: if all senders are local (this class or subclasses), then "private" is a good candidate to classify it. Methods without senders out of its class are often private services.

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented your second suggestion and am considering the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Here are a number of other well-known patterns:

instance creation

```
newStringBrick
    ^ GLMStringBrick new
```

default values

```
defaultDotsText
    ^ '...'
```

lazy initialization

```
items
    ^items ifNil: [ items := OrderedCollection new ]
```

And of course there are also lots of framework/application specific patterns. Sunit unit tests, seaside applications, magritte descriptions all have specific patterns. a very simple one is the magritte-description

```
descriptionArticle
    <magritteDescription>
    ^QCToOneOptionRelationDescription new
        accessor: #article;
        label: 'Article';
        options: self possibleArticles;
        priority: 40;
        classes: QCArticle allSubclasses;
        yourself.
```

[edit] And then the heuristics: another possibly good suggestion is the one I used last, or if you see a short repeating cycle the one that fits.

And would it be possible to find a good category for extension methods directly?

Comment: Thanks Stef. These are good examples (and hints) of method classifications that tend to appear frequently. My question however is related to heuristics on how to suggest a short but valuable list of category names for a given selector, similar to the intelligence we have for selector auto-completion (which can be quite sophisticated.)